# How can i set up both paired and unpaired data for t test in SPSS?

Tags: t-test, missing-data, paired-data, pre-post-comparison

My study involves a pre- and post-test knowledge score.

However, due to participants not understanding the unique identifier code generation, **some of the data collected is not able to be paired.**

Some successfully used the unique identifier code generation, and **we have some paired data.**

How can i incorporate both of these into analysis?

Comment: If the mistakenly unpaired data dominate, I would analyze all the data as unpaired. Otherwise I would analyze only paired data and throw out the unpaired.

Comment: There is also a way through split-plot analysis in ANOVA with respondents factor nested in the pre-post factor. I've never tried it myself, though, as a way to cope with the situation you describe.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25941/t-test-for-partially-paired-and-partially-unpaired-data,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215769/how-to-analyse-paired-data-lacking-pairing-information?noredirect=1&lq=1  solves maybe the problem for t-test. Please augment your question, what whould you have used if pairing was complete?